# uploading iOS App when collaborating with another company

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I'm collaborating with another company, and I'm trying sign with my 
developer account.

They invited me so I can see the App in ItunesConnect, but in Xcode I can't sign the App.

I'm getting an error:

```
"Failed to create provisioning profile"
```

and:

```
"no profile for 'com......' were found"
```

Screenshot:

[image: General Tab]

I don't understand what I'm missing, Please cane anyone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this'll help, but here goes.

In the financial company I work for, we have two accounts:

- a regular $99 developer account
- a $299 Enterprise Account, which we use for deploying in-house apps.

We have an iPad app in the App Store, with an App ID of "*MyProgram.MyCompany.com*".  Crucially, this App ID and it's Provisioning Profile was set up using our $99 regular account (which has rights to put apps on the App Store).

However, usually, I'm working with "in-house" apps using my Enterprise Account, and here, I am allowed to create all the App IDs I want **except** for that "*MyProgram.MyCompany.com*" ID.

The "Profiles & Certificates" webpage is of little help here, but the reason I'm not allowed to create an app with that ID is because it's already registered in our $99 account.

So, if I am working on a few in-house apps, and want to deploy an in-house version of this app, I *must* change my project to use a different App ID & Provisioning Profile.  Or, in Xcode, change to using the developer account which is a member of our $99 account.

It sounds like this might be the same problem you're seeing.

Does that help/make sense ?

Comment: so from what I understand I have to have a paying account to get provisioning from other companies.  so even if I see the app in the itunesconnect portal, it doesent help if I dont have apple developer paying account, is that correct ?

Comment: I think it's more a case of you needing to be logged into Xcode as a user who is part of the licensing scheme which has rights to that particular App ID and Provisioning Profile.   In other words, even if your "other company" sends you a Provisioning Profile certificate file to install on your Mac, that won't be enough.  It must correspond with the user you're running Xcode as.  And when you get any step wrong, you'll get a vague, unhelpful Xcode error.  ;-(

Comment: In Xcode, make sure your profile matches whatever user ID you use to log into iTunesConnect with.  Then, make sure you have a Code-Signing Certificate & Provisioning Profile for that App ID, and are able to select it in XCode.  (If you have installed these files, but can't view that in your project settings, this is a clue that you're not running Xcode as the correct user.)

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, I have 2 Apple Ids in: Perfences->Accounts. The account that I'm talking about I'm accessing it threw itunesconnect and I see the app that I was shard with. They gave me permissions of App-Manager. But in Xcode I'm not getting any provisionning profile. and I dont understand what I'm doing wrong.....